Unable to quit docker run with CTRL+C using exec format of ENTRYPOINT and CMD
In my Dockerfile, I was previously using the following CMD so that the Apache server would launch and since it was running in the foreground, the container would remain running and I could kill it using CTRL + C without issue.
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND", "-k", "start"]

I've since needed to update my Dockerfile so that I can run another script before Apache starts so I added an entrypoint script and modified my Dockerfile...
Dockerfile:
...

EXPOSE 80 

# Default process to run on container startup
ENTRYPOINT ["/entrypoint.d/docker-entrypoint.sh"]

# Default command to run container
CMD ["/usr/sbin/apachectl", "-D", "FOREGROUND", "-k", "start"]

docker-entrypoint.sh:
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Inject Environment Variables
source ${ENTRYPOINT_FOLDER}/env.sh

# Run the main container process (from the Dockerfile CMD)
exec "$@"

In both of these updated commands I'm using the exec form of ENTRYPOINT and CMD, the arguments set in CMD are to launch Apache in the foreground using the line exec "$@" in the entrypoint script, but doing this doesn't allow me to use CTRL + C any longer to quit from the terminal window.
What am I doing wrong here?

Which arguments are you using when you invoke docker run, docker exec, or similar? (This is a scenario where you shouldn't be using -i or -t -- when you plumb the terminal through to the program inside the container you give it the responsibility of deciding how it wants that TTY configured).

BTW, you should be sourceing env.sh if you want it to work as-intended, not running it as a subprocess.

docker run --env-file=<path-to-env-file> --rm --init -p 8080:80 --name <container-name> <image-name> @CharlesDuffy

@CharlesDuffy Thanks for that reminder, I will update it.

Do you still get the behavior without --init? (I expect you won't -- an init process isn't supposed to exit when it gets a SIGINT, since when init is running on bare hardware exiting PID 1 puts that system into a state where the kernel needs to either reboot or shut down).

CTRL+C doesn't behave as expected with or without the --init.

After sourcing the env.sh, aka source ${ENTRYPOINT_FOLDER}/env.sh, now I'm getting the error /entrypoint.d/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 9: exec: -k: invalid option when I execute docker run

Consider adding set -x; : "$0" "$@" to your entrypoint script before the exec to get some logs. I suspect that $0 is eating a value you intend to pass forward as an argument.

@CharlesDuffyHmmm, I'm not following what to change here, apologies, I'm a bit of a novice at bash. I thought using $@ would expand all of the items I passed in via CMD.

Just saw your prior comment, I'm trying that...

A bit of context: bash -c '...script...' arg0 arg1 arg2 puts the first argument after the script text into $0, whereas "$@" refers only to $1 and onwards. That's not necessarily going to happen here where your script is being invoked via an execve(), but... even if the problem isn't exactly what I was thinking, we may well learn something regardless; having logs is always to the better.

I took out the source script to keep this simple.  After adding set -x; : "$0" "$@", I get the following + : /entrypoint.d/docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND -k start and + exec /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND -k start, my container starts, but I still can't use CTRL+C to quit.

While I had used the proper exec forms for both ENTRYPOINT and CMD, the quit signal still wasn't working.
The resolution for this issue was to add the options -t and -i in my docker run invocation.
Before:
docker run --env-file=<env-file-path> --rm -p 8080:80 ...

After:
docker run --env-file=<env-file-path> -t -i --rm -p 8080:80 ...

Reference: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/2838#issuecomment-29205965
I also wanted to give a thank you to CharlesDuffy for helping me with this issue, I learned some things from you regarding debugging bash scripts. 
